# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView not working properly after orientation changes

Tags: android, react-native

while trying out [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview) with the Expo Go app and `npm create-react-native-app` on Android I noticed a weird behaviour after a device rotation.

1. When I launch the app in portrait mode and then switch to landscape the KeyboardAvoidingView cycles between **not getting pushed up at all** or **not getting pushed up enough** when tapping the TextInput. Also, when hiding the keyboard the button stays hidden every second time.
2. When I launch the app in landscape mode and then switch to portrait the KeyboardAvoidingView always gets pushed up way to much.

Here is a short clip showing what happens: [KeyboardAvoidingView and rotating device](https://somepi.ddns.net/nextcloud/index.php/s/R6ZzLdPEAJxXf9q)

How can one prevent this from happening?

Here is the code I used for `create-react-native-app` (I only changed the name of the component):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Platform,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Button,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={styles.inner}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Header</Text>
          <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={styles.textInput} />
          <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
            <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => null} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inner: {
    padding: 24,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom: 48,
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 36,
  },
  btnContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginTop: 12,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `keyboardVerticalOffset="-999999"` fixed the issue for me.
It seems that after rotating the device the **height** of the keyboard in landscape- and portraitmode are **added/subtracted** from each other, leading to this weird behaviour.